# Improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty} (\sqrt{x+\cos(x)}-\sqrt{x})\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to find out wether $\int_0^{+\infty}(\sqrt{x+\cos(x)}-\sqrt{x})dx$ is convergent, absolutely convergent, or divergent.

I'm already convinced that it is not absolutely convergent, since $$|\sqrt{x+\cos(x)}-\sqrt{x}|=\dfrac{|\cos(x)|}{\sqrt{x+\cos(x)}+\sqrt{x}}\ge \frac{1}{3}\dfrac{\cos^2(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$ for $x\ge 1$, and it's not hard to show that $\int_1^{+\infty}\dfrac{\cos^2(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx$ diverges.

I can't find any good idea for the convergence. My intuition is that it diverges.

Comment: Oh, it seems that the Dirichlet test proves that the integral is convergent! But I'm curious to find out if there are other solutions.

Comment: Your $\ge$ [is false for e.g.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%7Ccos%28x%29%7C%2F%28sqrt%28x%2Bcos%28x%29%29%2Bsqrt%28x%29%29-%28cos+x%29%5E2%2Fsqrt%289x%29+from+0+to+1) $x=0.2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does converge conditionally. By what you wrote above have
$$ \int_0^{\infty} (\sqrt{x+\cos x}-\sqrt{x}) \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\cos x}+\sqrt{x}} \, dx $$
and since
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\cos x}+\sqrt{x}} $$
is a decreasing function on $(0,\infty)$ tending to zero as $x \to \infty$ while $\cos x$ is uniformly bounded and has average value equal to zero, the improper integral converges by Dirichlet's test for integrals.

Comment: Is it easy to see that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\cos x}+\sqrt{x}}$ is decreasing?

Comment: Yes. Just compute $\frac{d}{dx} (\sqrt{x+\cos x}+\sqrt{x}) = \frac{1-\sin x}{2\sqrt{x+\cos x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} $ and observe this is positive on $(0, \infty)$ so this function is increasing; its reciprocal is therefore decreasing